# Is vine-covered an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

I'm having a problem understanding an adjective I found in a grammar book. The sentence is:

3. After an enormous Sunday dinner, the old farmer walked slowly to the vine-covered porch and eased into the creaking swing to begin this regular Sunday nap.

I got most of the answers right except for vine-covered. Is it some sort of double adjective, because both vine and covered are describing the porch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Compound Adjective](http://www.grammar.com/compound-adjectives/) is a ***well-known*** term.

Answer (score 4):

"Vine-covered" is a compound adjective, so--grammatically--it functions as a single word adjective does just as "blue" or "red" or "broken" would also describe the porch. It might help to rearrange the sentence in your mind by asking the question "what are the attributes of the porch?" which yields the response "the porch is covered in vines." Just as if it were a red porch, the answer would be "the porch is red".

Comment: Thank you! I've noticed that I have problems with grammar terms that are compound; I always assumed that an adjective etc is always one word.

Also, I just noticed something with the word covered. If I were to say "I covered the car with a dustbin bag.." would covered be a verb. So the word could potentially be an adjective as well as a verb?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Many adjectives end in "ed" or "ing", which you rightly associate with verbs. [Here's a link](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Adjectives_ED_ING.htm) to a page that deals with this phenomenon. (Perhaps you should be asking this as a new, proper question, rather than as a comment, though?)

Answer (score 0):

A vine-covered house is a house covered by vine. Snow-covered mountains are mountains covered by snow.
Useful information about compond adjectives here:
http://www.grammar.cl/english/compound-adjectives.htm